# Integrate rest API with code igniter mvc

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I have Vedic Rishi Astro API. I am integrating it with Codeigniter. But I don't know how to do it.

Vedic Rishi Provides Matchmaking API. They provided me with:

```
$birthdata = Array(
'm_day'=>16,
'm_month' =>3,
//more fields of male

'f_day'=>12,
'f_month' =>3,
//more fields of female

)
//Rest of their code
```

I am confused with how to integrate this code in the codeigniter. And I also need help on how to fetch details from database and add it in the array.